# Azure pipelines read only parameters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to protect the parameters of a pipelines by setting it to read only.
What I want to achieve to have a loop in an azure pipeline but that should not be changed from outside, so every time the number of the stages are kept. In the current implementation the parameters can be deleted or modified when someone wants to start a pipeline which can cause inconsistencies during the run.

Some relevant code:

```
parameters:
  - name: stage
    type: object
    default:
      - name: dev
      - name: test
      - name: prod
stages:
  - template: azure_pipeline_template.yml
    parameters:
      stage: ${{ parameters.stage }}
```

For simplicity I set three parameters dev, test, prod, and I want them to be always run, and they cannot be manually deleted when you hit run pipeline from ADO.

Is there any way to protect the parameters or have a loop with "hardcoded" values inside an azure pipeline?

Comment: Hi @Sunflame, may i know if there's any update? Please check my answer below and let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parameter` is used to **dynamically** select the stage as per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) below, not supported to set it as readonly.

[image]

It can be edited when you run the pipeline:

[image]

> For simplicity I set three parameters dev, test, prod, and I want them to be always run, and they cannot be manually deleted when you hit run pipeline from ADO.

You can simply add the stage one by one in yaml so that all will be executed.

```
stages:
- template: azure_pipeline_template.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    stage: dev

- template: azure_pipeline_template.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    stage: test

- template: azure_pipeline_template.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    stage: prod
```

If you would like to use **loop**, you can use variable instead:

```
variables:
  - name: stage
    value: dev, test, prod

stages:
- ${{ each stage in split(variables.stage, ', ') }}:
  - template: azure_pipeline_template.yml  # Template reference
    parameters:
      stage: ${{ stage }}
```

azure_pipeline_template.yml：

```
parameters:
- name: 'stage'  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  type: string

stages:
- stage: ${{ parameters.stage }}
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - script: echo ${{ parameters.stage }}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sunflame, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries. thanks.